# create instance from string value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi all I have the following code which works fine

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Company1");
    //Add the headers
    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ServiceNo";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "AccountNo";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Service";
    worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "CostCentre";
    //Add some items...
    int x = 2;
    worksheet.Cells["A" + x.ToString()].Value = 12001;
    worksheet.Cells["B" + x.ToString()].Value = "Nails";
    worksheet.Cells["C" + x.ToString()].Value = 37;
    worksheet.Cells["D" + x.ToString()].Value = 3.99;
    package.Save();
}
```

but I want to add multiple worksheet programmatically like this

```
List<string> compCodes = new List<string>();
//loop through records in db
compCodes.Add("comp1");
compCodes.Add("comp2");

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
    foreach (string comp in compCodes)
    {
        string company = "company" + comp;
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(company);
        //Add the headers
        worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ServiceNo";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "AccountNo";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Service";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "CostCentre";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Usage";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Usage";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "GrossRecurring";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "OneOffCharge";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Adjustments";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 10].Value = "Discount";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 11].Value = "TotalExVAT";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 12].Value = "VAT";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 13].Value = "Total";
        worksheet.Cells[1, 14].Value = "Source Bill Ref";
        int x = 1;
        worksheet.Cells["A" + x.ToString()].Value = 12001;
        worksheet.Cells["B" + x.ToString()].Value = "Nails";
        worksheet.Cells["C" + x.ToString()].Value = 37;
        worksheet.Cells["D" + x.ToString()].Value = 3.99;
    }
    package.Save();
}
```

I thought it was working but it is throwing an error when it tries to save

Error saving file C:\inetpub\download.xlsx

can anyone help

Comment: Did you have any luck on setting access rights?

Answer (score 0):

c:\inetpub is the default site folder for any website hosted through IIS. Your Web Application(& web Server) is by default configured to not have any access to your local file system on your machine.

You might want to create an **Access Rule for Site Folders** using the Official documentation from MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t32yf0a9(v=vs.100).aspx

Dependening on the Kind of authentication you're using there could be additional steps that apply all from the same page.